# Code only working in IE9 standards, Any way to downgrade?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, bookmarklet

The code does not work untill i manually hit F12, Hit Document Mode: IE9 standards and then only it decides to work.(And i really need to fix it as my target audience will otherwise be hitting F12 100 times a day, thats annoying. )
I know IE is crap but sadly i have no choice in the matter, and my target audience doesnt like to take a seconds time to change it to IE9 standards.
This is my code (Its a bookmarklet)

```
javascript:(function(){
    a=document.createElement('script');
    a.setAttribute('src','//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    data='[["#txtapplicantlname","agrawal","text"],["#txtapplicantfname","aayush","text"],["#txtfather","Ranjan","text"],["#txtmother","Neelam","text"],["#txtPincode","452010","text"],["#txtPhone","2147483647","text"],["#txtEmail","aayush@mail.com","text"],["#rdosex_0,#rdosex_1","1","radio"]]';
    for(a=$.parseJSON(data),b=a.length-1;0<=b;b--){
        c=a[b];
        if (c[2] == 'text') {
            console.log(c);
            $(c[0]).val(c[1]);
        } else if (c[2] == 'radio'){
            rdata = c[0].split(',');
            rnum = c[1] - 1;
            select = rdata[rnum];
            $(select).prop('checked', true);
            console.log(select);
        }
    }
})();
```

Note: In case someone is wondering, the data variable is being passed in as json like that because the bookmarklet is generated dynamically. The website it operates upon is HTTPS and hence i cannot make ajax calls to my server or they get blocked. 
Its job is to pretty much fillup web-forms, it generates a unique bookmarklet each time for that. Other browsers work fine but Internet Explorer just loves breaking down.. 
The code worked otherwise just before i added the radio buttons code, i am guessing it has something to do with .prop since it mentions it in the console..

Comment: The IIFE you are using is pointless because you aren't using the `var` statement, resulting in all of your variables leaking onto the global namespace.

Comment: @KevinB It's a bookmarklet...

Comment: Also, jQuery 2.0 will not work properly in IE<9

Comment: remove the console.log statements and try again.

Comment: jQuery 2.0 does not work in IE6,7,8. You need to debug why your browser is loading your page in a mode that is not IE9 standards.

Comment: Even in a bookmarklet you shouldn't leak tons of globals

Comment: @Ian Right, but that means it's going to execute directly on the page, similar to putting `alert(window.location.href)` in your addressbar, right?

Comment: I originally used var but for some reason it broke the <a> tag that i use to link to the bookmarklet. At the end of the var it would end the string and mess up the html and after some hard troubleshooting i had to just give up.. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: @KevinB I completely agree, but it doesn't make the IIFE pointless - I don't think that was its purpose.

Comment: I removed all the console.log statements altogether, still no effect though :/

Comment: You also need to wait for the script to load.

Comment: @KevinB I was just about to say that. I'm betting the code works when it's cached

Comment: Sadly no, i do wait for it to load. No effect yet..

Comment: @aayushdagra Show how you're waiting for it to load, because your current code doesn't

Comment: I got a JSFIDDLE running (Note: The HTML was copy pasted from the host). http://jsfiddle.net/RY5cg/

Comment: @Ian - I guess i pretty much wait till the website fully loads and the spinning wheel on the tab goes away..

Comment: @aayushdagra That doesn't mean the `script` element you created has loaded. Here's how I would write it: http://jsfiddle.net/JwkbA/ (note that you obviously shouldn't run it there, I just needed space to write it)

Comment: Its mostly for ease of convenience, currently a large part of my code pretty much generates a php array and then simply json_encodes it. It is very convinient for me as i have many different generators working and changing all of them can be a big pain and disrupt a big part of the code, i would really appreciate to avoid it..

Comment: Well Ian i used the code from the fiddle as the bookmarklet, but still no help..

Comment: I think the problem lies with my using .prop because the console gives an error about it, is there an alternative to that to checking a radio button?

Comment: Yes, `select.checked = true`

Comment: Kevin, that particular method didnt help but inspired by that i googled up and found an alternative to prop, replacing prop with attr did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @aayushdagra I don't understand what problems you are having. If you use a bookmarklet with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/JwkbA/1/ , on this page: http://jsfiddle.net/pbDRj/show/ , it works fine for me. And if you watch the console, you'll see some output

Comment: @aayushdagra I enjoy the way your first fiddle has `<link href="/Portal/Crop/js/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />` in it 12 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE does not understand console.log until the console is open. To fix change `console.log` to

```
window.console && console.log(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your browser is always going to a lower version of IE every time you open your page. a way to solve it is that if you want to force the user to load on the maximum IE browser version/ chrome version you should implement this following tag after the `<html>` tag

```
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

by doing this you force the browser to load on IE9 standars

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

Comment: I am not hosting the website or have any control or have any say in it for that matter sadly..

Comment: You can not modify the HTML where you place your script?? the console.log playsout in IE, try removing the console.log and see if you. otherwise try jQuery.